# How to draw characters to a Texture2D?

Tags: c#, xna, rendering

In C# XNA how is a single character drawn onto a `Texture2D` instead of the sprite batch ? I wish to do this in order to fill a `bool[,]` with the characters char\background data to analyze its shape.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to DrawString().

Comment: I havn't mentioned DrawString(), which I can't figure out how to use to draw onto a Texture2D anyway.

Comment: It was in the title, before I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a render target. The basic idea is instead of rendering your text to the back buffer, you render to a separate buffer, which can then give you a Texture2D.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

**question asker edit:**

With permission I've added to this answer. At time of writing the information on the MSDN is very out of date and makes it look more complicated than it need so I wrote my own example of how to do this.

The class this is done in may have to inherit from IDisposable and implement void Dispose() which does nothing.

```
PresentationParameters pp = graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters;
byte width = 20, height = 20; // for example

// pp.BackBufferWidth, pp.BackBufferHeight // for auto x and y sizes
RenderTarget2D render_target = new RenderTarget2D(graphicsDevice,
width, height, false, pp.BackBufferFormat, pp.DepthStencilFormat,
pp.MultiSampleCount, RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents);

graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(render_target);
graphicsDevice.Clear(...); // possibly optional
spriteBatch.Begin();
// draw to the spriteBatch
spriteBatch.End();
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); // Otherwise the SpriteBatch can't
// be used as a texture, this may also need to be done before using the
// SpriteBatch normally again to render to the screen.

// render_target can now be used as a Texture2D
```

At which point this might be useful. http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Texture_to_Colors.php

Comment: I'm stuck on step 1, where does GfxComponent come from?

Comment: it looks like GfxComponent.CreateRenderTarget(GraphicsDevice,
    1, SurfaceFormat.Single); is defined right below that section.  ie, GfxComponent is a class they're defining on that page.

Comment: ty. My GrapicsDevice's SetRenderTarget dosn't like (0, instance of shadowRenderTarget) as parameters but is ok when I take out the 0. Am continuing.

Comment: Reguarding you'r "if you check out step 3". The shadowRenderTarget I have created and configured dosn't have a drawString like SpriteBatch does, how do I draw the charecter onto it? Also I have an error where my class inheriting IDisposable does not implement Dispose(), can I use an empty method and in which case what is the return type?

Comment: it's been  a while since i've used spritebatch, but you should be able to use it just like you usually do...begin(), draw, end() where they have drawScene().  and yes, you can just supply an empty Dispose() - assuming you don't have any unmanaged resources that need to be disposed of.  it should return void.

Comment: Ahh, so you draw onto the SpriteBatch as normal then retreve from the SpriteBatch using the RenderTarget. I'm having to use http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet/ a lot. I hope after all this work this works! It's really simple what I'm after doing.

Comment: Excellent, tyvm, do you mind if I edit in working code for this to the end of you'r answer?

Comment: not at all, i'm sure others will find it useful as well.  glad i could help!